# How to automatically scroll to an anchor while audio plays

Tags: anchor, html5-audio

I'm working on an online learning portal. I have an audio player on a page designed by https://www.cleanhtmlplayer.com. I want to automatically scroll to an anchor of a page at specific timestamps of the audio.

For example, I have Anchor 1 and Anchor 2 in a webpage. As the audio is playing, I want the page to automatically scroll to Anchor 2 at the 5-minute mark. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a listener to the [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) event and take an action depending on the value of the [`currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) property.

If you rather prefer to use the Clean Html Player API, then when [initializing in javascript](https://docs.cleanhtmlplayer.com/configuration#alternative-js-initialisation-parameters-optional) on the `plyrOptions` argument, use the `listeners` property to bind to the `timeupdate` [event](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#events).